# How can I unmarshalling nested Object from a String format with JSON Jersey

Tags: java, json, jersey, marshalling, jackson

I know there are similar questions but any of them are usefull for me (or seem to be).

I need to execute following statements:

```
ClassA a = new ClassA(); 
String JSON_str = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(a);

ClassA a1 = (ClassA)objectMapper.readValue(JSON_str, ClassA.class);
ClassB b = (ClassB)a1.getAttribute1();
```

If i do the code above i receive following error:

"**java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to ClassB**"

The method getAttribute1 returns the ClassA attribute1 defined as "Object attribute1".
It will be initialized with an object of class B at runtime.

Please help me ^^.

Thank you in advance.
  Leonardo

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, `a1.getAttribute1()` return an object of type `java.util.LinkedHashMap`. So either change your code to:

```
ClassA a1 = (ClassA)objectMapper.readValue(JSON_str, ClassA.class);
java.util.LinkedHashMap b = (java.util.LinkedHashMap)a1.getAttribute1();
```

Or check the code in ClassA that populates this field and try to understand why it is not pupulating the object with `ClassB` instance.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the answer but the problem isn't in the way I populate the object a, the problem is into the "readValue" function that for some reason assigns the "LinkedHashMap" to attribute1.

Comment: unless `objectMapper` is some class you wrote there isn't much you can do about it, i just pointed out where the problem is, you can change the casting into `java.util.LinkedHashMap` and then manually read the values from it and set them to an object of ClassB